# What courses should I take in my Masters for PhD in mathematics - artificial intelligence?

Tags: education, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently enrolled in a masters programme in mathematics and I am taking mostly courses in mathematical statistics, but also dynamical systems and analysis. And I'm wondering if I want to go towards a career as a reasearcher of the mathematics of AI and similar, which courses should I pick in my masters degree? I wouls love if somebody who has gone down a similar path or something could help me out.

Much appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Here are some suggestions for courses that may be available to you: Optimization, Python, Data Structures, anything about neural networks.

Comment: These are really questions to take to your advisor and other people in your department.